# Find the eingenvalues for a specific integral operator

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

So i've been reading a book on func analysis and in the examples section there is a problem in which it is stated
Find the eigenvalues for $y = Kx$, where
$$y(t)=\int_{-1}^{1}(1-t\tau)x(\tau)d\tau.$$
In my undergrad linear algebra we did find eigenvalues, but only for matrix equations of the form $Tx=\alpha x$ where one looks for the eingenvalue of $det(T-I\lambda)=0$, where $T$ is some linear mapping.
Then one obtains a characteristic polynomial from which one obtains eigenvalue and then eigenvectors.
I don't know how to begin here.

Comment: What do you mean by "one finds the roots of $T-\lambda I )x=0$"? Presumably the examples section has something to do with what you can find in the book. Have you wrote down the definition of being an eigenvalue?

Comment: We did search for eingenvalues by taking a $det(T-\lambda I)$ then obtaining a characteristic polynomial from which we then solved a system which gets us eigenvectors. Something is an eigenvalue if it satisfies $Tx=\alpha x$.

Comment: The operator is two dimensional. The range  consists of linear functions. It shouldn't be hard to find its eigenvectors.

Comment: Can you please explain to me how I would go about doing it. A procedure that is. In the the book only Theorems are given with no examples.

Comment: Apply $T$ to $x(\tau)=a\tau +b.$ The outcome will be some other linear function depending on $a$ and $b.$ Then find all $a$ and $b$ so that $Tx=\lambda x$ for some $\lambda.$ You may use $2\times 2$ determinants as well

Comment: Could you start the procedure yourself, since I do not know how to proceed even with your instructions . I am sorry, I just have not seen a single example of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$(Tx)(t)=\int\limits_{-1}^1x(\tau)\,d\tau -t\,\int\limits_{-1}^1\tau x(\tau)\,d\tau $$
The right hand side is of the form $a+bt,$ where
$a=\int\limits_{-1}^1x(\tau)\,d\tau$ and $b=-\int\limits_{-1}^1\tau x(\tau)\,d\tau.$
We have $\ker T\neq \{0\}$ as the operator is finite dimensional.
Actually we may indicate a nonzero element in $\ker T$ explicitly: $x(t)=3t^2-1.$

Any  eigenvector corresponding to a nonzero eigenvalue must of the form $a+bt.$ The natural base if the two dimensional subspace  of linear functions $a+bt$  consists of $1$ and $t.$ We have  $T1=2$ and $Tt=-{2\over 3}t.$ Since the subspace  is two dimensional,  the eigenvalues of $T$ are $2,$  $-{2\over 3}$ and $0.$

Comment: Thank you so much for writing this. May I ask something more.
When we substitute x(t) as a linear function, that is $x(t)=at+b$ and substituting it back in, we get
$$\lambda (at+b)=2b-\frac{2at}{3}.$$ Simplifying we get
$$3b(2-\lambda)=at(\lambda +2)$$. This equation has 4 variables, and discussing on the possibilities, we get $$1~~. b=0\land at=0,$$ $$2.~~ 2-\lambda =0\land at=0$$, $$3.~~ 3b=0\land \lambda +2=0$$ as possibilities. How do i eliminate the ones which arent eigenvalues, and how do i obtain the ones you found. Since obviously here i get many possbilities...

Comment: According to me we have $T(a+bt)=2a -{2\over 3}bt.$ Therefore the eigenvalue equation is $2a-{2\over 3}bt=\lambda(a+bt).$ This is the equality between two linear functions, hence the coefficients must be equal. Thus $2a=\lambda a$ and $-{2\over 3}b=\lambda b.$ If $a\neq 0,$ then $\lambda =2$ and $b=0.$ If $b\neq 0$ then $\lambda=-{2\over 3}$ and $a=0.$

Comment: There was an error in my answer which I have just corrected. One of the eigenvalues is equal $-{2\over 3},$ not $-{4\over 3}.$ Your second equation after "simplifying" is wrong. You should get $$3b(2-\lambda)=at(3\lambda +2)$$ The equation holds for all $-1\le t\le 1.$ So either $\lambda =2$ or $\lambda=-{2\over 3}.$

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! All is good now

Answer (score 4):

In fact, the characteristic equation $\mathrm{det}(A-\lambda) = 0$ means that the matrix $A-\lambda$ is singular, because it is originally derived from the equation $Av = \lambda v$, which is the actual eigenvalue problem.

In the present case, if we denote the eigenfunction associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ by $x_\lambda(t)$, then we have to solve the following problem :
$$
\int_{-1}^1 (1-t\tau)x(\tau) \,\mathrm{d}\tau = \lambda x_\lambda(t)
$$
We get
$$
\lambda\dot{x}_\lambda(t) = -\int_{-1}^1 \tau x(\tau) \,\mathrm{d}\tau
$$
by differentiating once and $\lambda\ddot{x}_\lambda(t) = 0$ by differentiating twice. In consequence, the eigenfunctions are linear, i.e. $x_\lambda(t) = at+b$. Now, plugging this result back into the eigenvalue problem, one has :
$$
\int_{-1}^1 (1-t\tau)(a\tau+b) \,\mathrm{d}\tau = \lambda(at+b),
$$
After evaluation of the integral, this relation will permit to determine the possible values of $a$, $b$ and $\lambda$.